# Function doesn't updates Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written this small function which has two update two column. But it doesn't works how it should work. There's a column in the table named as **currentstatus** it's value has to be changed from *Queued* to *Completed* and a column **usedtimes** whose values needs to be incremented by +1. The increment doesn't happen as well.

I've been trying to fix this past couple of hours..but this doesn't seem to work.

What might be the issue?
Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
function updateMessageQueue($indexid)
{
    //this function would update that the messagequeue has been completed
    $status = "Completed";
    global $conn;
    try
    {
        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE messagequeue set currentstatus = :currentstatus AND usedtimes = usedtimes+1 where indexid = :index ");
        $statement->bindParam(':currentstatus',$status);
        $statement->bindParam(':index',$indexid);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace the `AND` with a `,`, which is the proper syntax for `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
UPDATE messagequeue set currentstatus = :currentstatus , usedtimes = usedtimes+1 
where indexid = :index
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got an **`AND`** keyword where a comma is expected.

<strike>The SQL syntax is invalid.</strike> As Bill Karwin points out, the SQL syntax *is* valid.

The `AND` keyword causes this expression:

```
:currentstatus AND usedtimes = usedtimes+1
```

to be evaluated in boolean context, so the expression will return either a zero or NULL; and the result of that expression is assigned to the `currentstatus` column.

Comment: +1 but the syntax is technically legal, just don't do what the OP intends. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin: yes, as always, you are right. The syntax _is_ legal, it just cause the entire expression to be evaluated in a boolean context.